# MSACCESS Is there a way for a query with a Boolean field to echo the string representation of the Boolean without taking way it's boolean type?

Tags: ms-access, boolean

Is there a way in a query for Microsoft Access to have a field that tests likeness of two fields and return the string representation of "True" or "False" instead of a -1 or 0 without loosing the boolean type?

```
 SQL SYNTAX
 [Table1].[Field1]=[Table2].[Field1] AS Compare
```

I would like it to be easy something like

```
 Cstr([Table1].[Field1]=[Table2].[Field1])
```

Although I know I could just write a function in VBA to achieve the same effect I'm wondering if there is already a way to represent a Boolean with it's string value without taking away the Boolean nature from it's type.

And I also want to avoid doing

```
 iff([Table1].[Field1]=[Table2].[Field1], "True", "False")
```

As although it will visually do the job, it will mean that I will have to make any programmatic comparisons look for the string value of "True" "true" "TRUE"... instead of it's intended function as a yes/no in the first place.

I mainly find this a minor annoyance since in the intermediate window of VBA I can clearly see the string value like this

```
 debug.? "a"="a"
 True
```

And I don't get why it's not consistent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the *Format* property to *True/False* for your query's boolean field expression.

[image: Property Sheet for query field showing Format property]

*True/False* is not included in the choices available in the Format drop down box, but you can type it in.

Applying that format to both field expressions in this query ...

```sql
SELECT (1=1) AS boolean_True, (1=2) AS boolean_False
FROM Dual;
```

... gives me this result in Datasheet View:

```
boolean_True boolean_False
------------ -------------
        True         False
```

The underlying values are still Access booleans (integer -1 or 0).  Just the presentation of those values is changed.